# Textbox value not changing in webmethod result

Tags: c#, jquery, webmethod

Here Webmethod return value correctly and the label value change as per the condition but the value of txtusername is not changing

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<p style="margin: 0 0 5px 0;"><b>User Name</b>&nbsp;<span class="pull-right">
    <asp:Label ID="usernamelbl" Font-Size="X-Small" runat="server"></asp:Label></span></p>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Enter UserName" 
OnChange="CheckUserName(this)"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
 function CheckUserName(oName) {
                PageMethods.UserNameChecker(oName.value, OnSucceeded);
            }
            function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
                lbl = document.getElementById('<%=usernamelbl.ClientID %>');
                lbl1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>');
                if (methodName == "UserNameChecker") {
                    if (result == true) {
                        lbl.innerHTML = 'Try Another Username';
                        lbl.style.color = "red";
                        $('<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>').val('');
 lbl1.style.color = "Blue";
                    }
                    else {
                        lbl.innerHTML = '';
                    }
                }
            }
```

this works (lbl1.style.color = "Blue";)fine but the value is not changeing. I also try lbl1.innerHTML = ''; but failed
 Please Help me

Comment: have you try `lbl1.value = "something"`? not sure why you use half javascript half jquery though

Comment: @seOng11 Thank you its works .. is it not a good method ?? i am not expect in jquery . just a beginner .

Comment: not saying is not a good method, just in long run, it will become spaghetti and hard to resolve in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
lbl1.value = "something"
```

for the way of you writing, you did not fully utilise `jquery`

instead of

```
lbl1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>');
```

you can write as

```
lbl1 = $('input[id$="txtUserName"]');
```

`id$` means that id that end with

then you can use `lbl1.val("something")` to populate it

and you can abandon the below script,

```
$('<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>').val('');
```

if you insist of using it, you need to add

```
$('#' +'<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>').val('');
```